# Задачка на регулярные выражения не проходит тесты на сайте

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Решал на регулярки задачку [отсюда](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=80):

> Вам необходимо проверить домашнюю работу Васи Пупкина, в которой он написал равенство. Например, запись вида «2+3=5» является правильной, а «23*7=421» неверная, но корректная. Корректной записью выражения будем называть последовательность: число, операция («+», «-», «*», «/»), число, знак равенства, число. Числом будем считать последовательность из одной или более десятичных цифр, перед которой может стоять один знак минус. В корректной записи выражения нет пробелов.
>   В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите «YES», если указанная запись правильна (т.е. равенство представляет собой тождество), «NO» - если корректная, но неверная и «ERROR», если запись некорректная.

Ну и не проходит даже первый тест.  Для проверки переделал решение в функцию с ассертами. Гляньте кто - где я затупил?
Все мыслимые варианты проходит...

```
import re
# =============================================================================
# 
# with open('INPUT.TXT') as f:
#     line = f.read()
# =============================================================================
def t(line):
    mo = re.fullmatch(r'(?P<n1>-?\d+)(?P<oper>[-/\*\+])(?P<n2>-?\d+)=(?P<n3>-?\d+)',
                      line)
    result = "ERROR" 
    if len(line) <=100  and mo:
        n1 =  int(mo.groupdict()['n1'])
        n2 =  int(mo.groupdict()['n2'])
        n3 =  int(mo.groupdict()['n3'])
        if max(n1,n2,n3)<30000 and min(n1,n2,n3)>-30000:
            oper = mo.groupdict()['oper']
            if oper == "/"  and  n2==0:
                result = "NO"
            else:
                m = lambda x,y: x*y
                d = lambda x,y: x/y
                s = lambda x,y: x+y
                _ = lambda x,y: x-y
                do = {"*":m, "/":d, "+":s, "-":_}
                result = "YES" if n3 == do[oper](n1,n2) else "NO"

    return result

# =============================================================================
# with open('OUTPUT.TXT', 'w') as f:
#     f.write(result)
# 
# =============================================================================

assert t("er") == "ERROR"
assert t('1+-1=1') == "NO"
assert t('1+-1=-0') == "YES"
assert t('-31+-1=-32') == "YES"
assert t('2*=3') ==  "ERROR"
assert t('173') ==  "ERROR"
assert t('2+2=a') ==  "ERROR"
assert t('two plus three is five') ==  "ERROR"
assert t('2+3=5') == "YES"
assert t('3*7=20') == "NO"
assert t('3*7=21') == "YES"
assert t('3-7=-4') == "YES"
assert t('0/7=0') == "YES"
assert t('7/0=0') == "NO"
assert t('---=-') == "ERROR"
assert t('') == "ERROR"
```

Comment: Быть может, в INPUT.TXT в конце случайно присутствует символ переноса строки, который вы не удаляете (но это не точно)

Comment: @andreymal 100%. 
Вставил  `line = line.replace('\n',"")`  и все заработало.
Ну такое... 3 часа мучений из-за неопрятности администраторов....

Comment: Используйте `re.match(r'(?P<n1>-?\d+)(?P<oper>[-/*+])(?P<n2>-?\d+)=(?P<n3>-?\d+)$',  line)`

Comment: @VasylKolomiets ну не то чтобы неопрятности, перенос строки в конце файлов — стандартная практика в Unix-подобных ОС. А вот то, что в подобных задачах я ни разу не встречал уточнений про используемые переносы, грустно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.fullmatch` *возвращает объект соответствия, **если строка, как целое, полностью соответствует шаблону**, в противном случае возвращает `None`* ([см. здесь](http://pythonz.net/references/named/re.fullmatch/)).

В вашем случае, так как в конце строки присутствует перенос строки, нужно либо учитывать пробельные символы в вашем регулярном выражении, добавив `\s*` в конце:

```
re.fullmatch(r'(?P<n1>-?\d+)(?P<oper>[-/*+])(?P<n2>-?\d+)=(?P<n3>-?\d+)\s*', line)
                                                                        ^^^
```

либо используйте `re.match`, а в регулярном выражении добавьте `$`, который находит конец строки или позицию перед последним знаком в строке, если это символ перевода строки:

```
re.match(r'(?P<n1>-?\d+)(?P<oper>[-/*+])(?P<n2>-?\d+)=(?P<n3>-?\d+)$', line)
  ^^^^^^                                                           ^
```

Демо:

```
import re
line="-12+34=22\n"
print(re.fullmatch(r'(?P<n1>-?\d+)(?P<oper>[-/*+])(?P<n2>-?\d+)=(?P<n3>-?\d+)\s*', line))
# => <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='-12+34=22\n'>

print(re.match(r'(?P<n1>-?\d+)(?P<oper>[-/*+])(?P<n2>-?\d+)=(?P<n3>-?\d+)$', line))
# => <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='-12+34=22'>
```